# Monitoring with Wireshark on Wirless Networks

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, monitoring

I'm a beginner and started working with Wireshark and hacking and I have some questions about it.
The monitoring of a particular computer does not always work immediately.

Why does the monitoring of a particular computer only work when it reconnects to the network or waits for some time?
And is it possible to force a reconnection of the target computer to the network?

Is there a difference that can observe in monitored traffic for encrypted and unencrypted connections?

Comment: I use Comm View for packet sniffing, but I have used Wireshark before. (1) it is not the job of Comm View or WIreshark to start a remote connection (2) packet sniffers like these do do not decrypt packets. You would need a third party tool for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the monitoring of a particular computer only work when it reconnects to the network or waits for some time?

If the target isn't connected to the network, it obviously isn't sending traffic that you could trace. Since we're talking about WiFi traffic, it might be possible that the target device shuts down the WiFi connection or even disables the WiFi adapter after certain amount of inactivity time. WiFi is pretty expensive powerwise, so for example Apple devices tend to do this. That's one of the sources of the stellar battery times.

> And is it possible to force a reconnection of the target computer to the network?

Not with Wireshark or any other monitoring tool I'm aware of.

> Is there a difference that can observe in monitored traffic for encrypted and unencrypted connections?

I'm not sure I understand the question. Data in an unencrypted connection is, well, unencrypted. As an example you can analyze HTML traffic, and from the payload directly read the content of the packets; meaning you can basically re-create an entire webpage just by snooping the payloads, should you be so inclined. In encrypted traffic the only thing you can see is sender/receiver addresses etc. Since the payload is encrypted, it's showing up as unintelligible garbage.

Comment: thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome :-)